# Access: How to automatically create a record in related tables

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have an access db with two tables (i.e. Ta, Tb) where records of Tb relate to records of Ta. 
When a new record in Ta is created I need to automatically create a new empty record in Tb which relates to the new Ta record. What is the easiest way to do this?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Generally you would accomplish something like this by using database triggers.  Unfortunately, I don't believe MS Access supports triggers.  If you have the ability to use MS SQL, you would then be able to use triggers.

I found [this post](http://p2p.wrox.com/access/33010-trigger-access-2003-a.html#post187409) that talks about some alternative methods of accomplishing what you're looking for.

Comment: I can use MS SQL if it is supported by Acces. may you exaplain me better how?

Comment: MS SQL is an alternative to Access.  Here is a free version: http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Access doesnt have stored procedures but you can use the

After_Insert. event
then run an insert query.

populate the insert query with a select from the master Ta to get the max id so you can put that in Tb

Answer (score 0):

From Ribbon:

1. **Create >> Queries >> Query Design**

Include the following as query fields

1.1 The uniquely-related field (e.g., **UniqueID**) from both **Ta** and **Tb**.

1.2 At least one other field from each of **Ta** and **Tb** (e.g., **FieldX_Ta**, **FieldY_Tb**)

1.3 Save (e.g., **QueryA**).

So there are at least 4 query fields in **QueryA** now
(**UniqueID** from **Ta**, **UniqueID** from **Tb**, **FieldX_Ta1**, **FieldY_Tb**).

Selecting **QueryA** at Navigation Pane,

2. **Create >> Forms >> Form**

2.1 Set default value, for both **FieldX_Ta** and **FieldY_Tb**.

2.2 Design as desired and Save (e.g., **Form_I**).

3. Opening **From_I** @Form View

3.1 Go to "New records".

3.2 Fill in forms. Once Save, both **Ta** and **Tb** should have new records related via **UniqueID**.

[I'm using MS Access Version 2304 (Build 16327.20214)].